# xsltlistviewwebpart does not fit TD of table

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part

I've put td width to 20% but it seems like the xsltlistviewwebpart does not fit to 20%. Basically it takes about 50% of the td cell. how can I make it fit or wordwrap on the cell.
Here's a sample code

```
<td id="_invisibleIfEmpty" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" valign="top" width="20%"> 

                <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="loc:FullPage" ID="FullPage" FrameType="TitleBarOnly"><ZoneTemplate>
                <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" ViewFlag="" ViewSelectorFetchAsync="False" InplaceSearchEnabled="False" ServerRender="False" ClientRender="True" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" WebId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" IsClientRender="False" GhostedXslLink="thread.xsl" NoDefaultStyle="" ViewGuid="{7BA153D6-334C-458C-9546-77ABC74E4A08}" EnableOriginalValue="False" ViewContentTypeId="" ListUrl="" ListDisplayName="" ListName="{422513C1-9F10-4A39-89A4-E369A5421DE7}" ListId="422513c1-9f10-4a39-89a4-e369a5421de7" PageSize="-1" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" DataSourceID="" ShowWithSampleData="False" AsyncRefresh="False" ManualRefresh="False" AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" Title="NewsFeed" FrameType="Default" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" Description="" IsIncluded="True" ZoneID="FullPage" PartOrder="2" FrameState="Normal" AllowRemove="True" AllowZoneChange="True" AllowMinimize="True" AllowConnect="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowHide="True" IsVisible="True" CatalogIconImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/itdisc.png?rev=44" TitleUrl="/Lists/NewsFeed" DetailLink="/Lists/NewsFeed" HelpLink="" HelpMode="Modeless" Dir="Default" PartImageSmall="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageLarge="/_layouts/15/images/itdisc.png?rev=44" IsIncludedFilter="" ExportControlledProperties="False" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ID="g_7ba153d6_334c_458c_9546_77abc74e4a08" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{7BA153D6-334C-458C-9546-77ABC74E4A08}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" __designer:CustomXsl="Fldtypes_mswhTitle.xsl;fldtypes_Ratings.xsl" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""><ParameterBindings>
```

Comment: the xslt webpart is actually a newsfeed, I wanted to shrink it so it does not take up so much space. I try not to use "Appearance Width of the webpart"  and set to a specific value because I am not sure how it will look like for pc/laptop with higher resolution... how can I make it such that it follows the size of the table td???

Answer (score 0):

Where is the closing tag of  ? Have you tried to inspect the element and check if the width of that td is correctly 20%?

You could also try to set the width using css and mark the inline style as important, like:

```
<td style="width:20% !important;"><!-- Your XSLT List View Web Part --></td>
```

Comment: When I inspect element I can see the div tags. But when I look at the aspx page in SPD, the div tags are not there? Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Since xsltlistview web part is likely to generate its own html layout, it is possible that the div was generated by the xsltlistview web part itself. How about the 20% width? Did you succeed to achieve it using the above css styling?

Comment: yup tried that but no go